# In IE 6+ Transition or Flash would be better to use for small drop in-out animations

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, flash, css-transitions

IE6+ got some problems with transition as usual but i know ways to get trough those but the thing im wondering if i use flash instead of getting nerfed by transition lacks would it make my website better or lamer? Cause if i use .swf files even for smallest animations i guess it would drop the performance really badly but would look better. Essipecially while im using opacity transition.

So which would be better to use on IE6+ or What would u expect from a website while browsing with IE6+? A good looking .swf with a performance lack or a crappy looking transition with good performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get ie6 out of your mind.  Take a look at the percentage share of people using ie6...

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

1.2% in november and december 2011!

Quit supporting it!